# Shoot problem: How to show a bullet before shoot?

Tags: python, pygame, bulletphysics

**I would like the 'banana' to be shown when the space bar is pressed, while it follows the character movement, and then to be fired upon the release of the same.**

```
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *
    
    
    #inizializzazione
    pygame.init()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((400,750))
    pygame.display.set_caption('MonkeyBanana')
    FPS=60
    
    
    
    #load image
    img_ground = pygame.image.load('Surf/sfondo.jpg').convert_alpha()
    surf_ground=pygame.transform.scale(img_ground,(img_ground.get_width(),screen.get_height()))
    
    
    class Monkey (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.sprites = [pygame.transform.scale((pygame.image.load('Surf/Animazioni/monkey_idle_00.png').convert_alpha()),
                                                   (screen.get_width() / 5, screen.get_height() / 7)),
                            pygame.transform.scale((pygame.image.load('Surf/Animazioni/monkey_idle_01.png').convert_alpha()),
                                                   (screen.get_width() / 5, screen.get_height() / 7)),
                            pygame.transform.scale((pygame.image.load('Surf/Animazioni/monkey_idle_02.png').convert_alpha()),
                                                   (screen.get_width() / 5, screen.get_height() / 7)),
                            pygame.transform.scale((pygame.image.load('Surf/Animazioni/monkey_idle_03.png').convert_alpha()),
                                                   (screen.get_width() / 5, screen.get_height() / 7))
                            ]
    
            self.launch_monkey=[]
            for i in range(0, 19):
                filename = "Surf/Animazioni/monkey_{:0>3}.png".format(i)
                img = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
                img_reduced = pygame.transform.scale(img, (screen.get_width() / 5, screen.get_height() / 7))
                self.launch_monkey.append(img_reduced)
    
            self.count=0
            self.count1 = 0
    
    
            self.image = self.sprites[self.count]
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.midbottom = (screen.get_width() / 2, screen.get_height())
            all_sprites.add(self)
    
        def update(self):
            self.count += 0.08
            if self.count >= 3:
                self.count = 0
            self.image = self.sprites[int(self.count)]
            if move_right and monkey.rect.right < screen.get_width():
                monkey.rect.x += 5
            elif move_left and monkey.rect.left > 0:
                monkey.rect.x -= 5
    
        def launch(self):
            global launch
    
            if launch:
                self.count1 += 1
                if self.count1 >= 19:
                    self.count1 = 0
                    launch = False
                self.image = self.launch_monkey[int(self.count1)]
    
    
    class Banana (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.image= pygame.transform.scale((pygame.image.load('Surf/banana.png').convert_alpha()),
                                               (screen.get_width() / 10, screen.get_height() / 15))
            self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = monkey.rect.center
            all_banana.add(self)
```

**here is the problem.** Everything works fine on the first launch. The second time I press the space bar, the banana returns to the character's hands instead of continuing the run.

```
        def update(self):
            global new_banana
            if keep_banana:
                self.rect.center = monkey.rect.center
                new_banana=False
    
            if launch_banana:
                self.rect.y -= 5
    
            if self.rect.top<50:
                self.kill()
    
    
    #create sprite and Group
    
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    all_banana= pygame.sprite.Group()
    monkey=Monkey()
    
    
    #other variables
    move_right=False
    move_left=False
    launch=False
    launch_banana=False
    keep_banana=False
    new_banana=False
    
    
    
    #principal cicle
    done=False
    while not done:
    
        for ev in pygame.event.get():
            if ev.type == QUIT:
                done = True
            if ev.type ==KEYDOWN:
                if ev.key== K_RIGHT:
                    move_right=True
                    idle = False
                if ev.key== K_LEFT:
                    move_left = True
                    idle = False
                if ev.key==K_SPACE:
                    keep_banana = True
                    new_banana=True
    
            elif ev.type ==KEYUP:
                if ev.key== K_RIGHT:
                    move_right=False
                    idle = True
                if ev.key== K_LEFT:
                    move_left=False
                    idle = True
                if ev.key==K_SPACE:
                    launch_banana=True
                    keep_banana = False
                    launch = True
    
        #Game logic
        if new_banana:
            banana=Banana()
    
        #screen update
    
    
        screen.blit(surf_ground, (0, 0))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        all_banana.draw(screen)
        all_banana.update()
        all_sprites.update()
        monkey.launch()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(FPS)
    
    #end principal cicle
    pygame.quit()
```

It works to me in another version without classes,by adding the banana to a new group every time it is fired, but I can't get it to work on the classes. I have tried so many times, but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`launch_banana` makes the banana fly:

> ```py
> if launch_banana:
>    self.rect.y -= 5
> ```

`launch_banana` is `False` at the beginning, but it is never set `False` again once it has become `True`. You have to set `launch_banana` to `False` when `keep_banana` is set `True`:

```py
launch_banana=False
keep_banana=False
new_banana=False

# [...]

while not done:

    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        # [...]

        if ev.type == KEYDOWN:
            # [...]

            if ev.key == K_SPACE:
                launch_banana = False        # <---
                keep_banana = True
                new_banana = True

        elif ev.type == KEYUP:
            # [...]

            if ev.key == K_SPACE:
                launch_banana = True
                keep_banana = False
                launch = True
```

---

Anyway, instead of all these Boolean variables, I propose to add a state to the `Banana` class. The state can be "keep" at the beginning and can be changed to "launched" after the banana is started.

```py
class Banana (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image= pygame.transform.scale((pygame.image.load('Surf/banana.png').convert_alpha()),
                                               (screen.get_width() / 10, screen.get_height() / 15))
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = monkey.rect.center
        all_banana.add(self)

        self.state = "keep"

    def start(self):
        self.state = "launched"

    def update(self):
        if self.state == "keep":
            self.rect.center = monkey.rect.center
    
        elif self.state == "launched":
            self.rect.y -= 5
    
        if self.rect.top<50:
            self.kill()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply

So

implement the launch_banana= False in Space Keydown don't work:

```
     if ev.key == K_SPACE:
            launch_banana = False        # <---
            keep_banana = True
            new_banana = True
```

I  implemented the banana states in this way in the game logic and work fine, by creating 2 sprite group:

```
        import pygame
        from pygame.locals import *


        #inizializzazione
        pygame.init()
        screen=pygame.display.set_mode((400,750))
        pygame.display.set_caption('MonkeyBanana')
        FPS=60



        #load image
        img_ground = pygame.image.load('Surf/sfondo.jpg').convert_alpha()
        surf_ground=pygame.transform.scale(img_ground,(img_ground.get_width(),screen.get_height()))


        class Monkey (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
            [...]

        class Banana(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
            def __init__(self):
                super().__init__()
                self.image = pygame.transform.scale((pygame.image.load('Surf/banana.png').convert_alpha()),
                                                    (screen.get_width() / 10, screen.get_height() / 15))
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.rect.center = monkey.rect.center
                one_banana.add(self)   <-------------GroupSingle

                self.state = "keep"


            def start(self):
                self.state = "launched"

            def update(self):
                if self.state == "keep":
                    self.rect.center = monkey.rect.center

                elif self.state == "launched":
                    self.rect.y -= 5

                if self.rect.top < 50:
                    self.kill()


        #create sprite and Group

        all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        all_banana= pygame.sprite.Group()
        one_banana= pygame.sprite.GroupSingle() <------add this group
        monkey=Monkey()


        #other variables
        move_right=False
        move_left=False
        launch=False
        launch_banana=False
        keep_banana=False
        new_banana=False



        #principal cicle
        done=False
        while not done:

            for ev in pygame.event.get():
                if ev.type == QUIT:
                    done = True
                if ev.type ==KEYDOWN:
                    if ev.key== K_RIGHT:
                        move_right=True
                        idle = False
                    if ev.key== K_LEFT:
                        move_left = True
                        idle = False
                    if ev.key==K_SPACE:
                        keep_banana = True
                        new_banana=True

                elif ev.type ==KEYUP:
                    if ev.key== K_RIGHT:
                        move_right=False
                        idle = True
                    if ev.key== K_LEFT:
                        move_left=False
                        idle = True
                    if ev.key==K_SPACE:
                        launch_banana=True
                        keep_banana = False
                        launch = True

            #Game logic
            **if new_banana:
                banana=Banana()
                if launch_banana:
                    one_banana.empty()
                    all_banana.add(banana)   <------The new logic works
                    banana.start()
                    launch_banana=False
                    new_banana=False**



            #screen update


            screen.blit(surf_ground, (0, 0))
            all_sprites.draw(screen)
            all_banana.draw(screen)
            one_banana.draw(screen)
            one_banana.update()
            all_banana.update()
            all_sprites.update()
            monkey.launch()
            pygame.display.flip()
            pygame.time.Clock().tick(FPS)

        #end principal cicle
        pygame.quit()
```

There is a way much simple to do this?
Thank you in any case